# Is there a way to connect display layouts in 360 degrees?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get the mouse to go from the right side of screen 1 to the left side of screen 3 but also be able to go back to screen 3 from the left side of screen 1 through left side of screen 2 in a 360 degree pattern.

Here is an example I made of what I would hope the layout to look like if possible

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AbW4mEN.png]

Comment: Without third party software, no. With third party software, maybe (Although I have not found any). Perhaps with Synergy you may be able to by linking to your own self on it? You can specify which monitor you want synergy to goto I know.

Answer (score 0):

I started googling because I really like this idea. I found an old stack post from 6 years ago that led me to this.

http://graphics.cs.columbia.edu/projects/m3/index.html

It lets you assign a mouse position to a keyboard shortcut, or maybe an unused mouse button. So you can hit a key and be where you need to be.

OR

Maybe mouse acceleration might better suit you, if its set appropriately a flick of the wrist should travel across multiple monitors very quickly... Although, then its a game of where the heck is the mouse.